# Как синхронизировать WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, развертывание, localhost

Есть достаточно простой сайт на WordPress. С WordPress я пока ещё только знакомлюсь. Я хочу синхронизировать локальную разработку с сервером. Бэкапы, которые делает плагин, который сейчас там стоит (BackUpWordPress), занимают по 100 мб. Мне представляется, что моих данных там мегабайтов на 5. Но сайт в итоге весит видимо намного больше. В идеале я бы хотел сделать маленький локальный репозиторий, для моих данных, актуальное состояние из которого синхронизируется с сервером, так чтобы остальные 100 мб, вероятно, относящиеся к плагинам, выкачивались и заполнялись моими настройками автоматически. Если это возможно, какое для этого возможно решение?

Comment: git, svn или любая система контроля версий

Comment: git------------

Comment: Не понял суть вашего комментария?

Comment: Если вопрос что я использую, то гит. А прочерки, потому что минимальная длина комментария 15.

Comment: Ну так и используйте гит, в чем у вас сложность?

Comment: Ну вопрос у меня не про то как пользоваться гитом. Если я плохо сформулировал свою задачу, я могу её уточнить.

Comment: Добавьте тему и нужные плагины в гит и коммитьте и пушьте изменения в продакшн или я не понял вопроса)

Comment: Возможно. Может я плохо сформулировал. Я хочу админить не сервер напрямую, а работать с маленьким локальным репозиторием, и чтобы это синхронизировалось с сервером, и остальные 100 мб, которые создаются вордпрессом или плагинами создавались или выкачивались сами, а не хранились в моём компактном репозитории.

Comment: вопрос такой: меняете только файлы темы или плагины свои ? Вообще по workflow с вордпресом долго тоже думал (т.к. бывает нужно делать небольшие сайты и поддерживать), есть некоторые мысли, могу поделиться, если у Вас работа не связана с копанием в движке самом, а только с изменением темы или плагина своего.

Comment: А вы плагины как выкачиваете? Сможете описать все эти действия кодом (на баше, например)? Конфигурировать что-то нужно?

Comment: @mihdan код плагинов в гит - вариант не очень хороший. Должно быть достаточно названий, версий и конфигов.

Answer (score 2):

Если проблема в перекачке 100 мб файлов туда-сюда, то можно:

1. Пойти методом грубой силы и денег, купив более широкий канал.
2. Использовать `rsync` для выгрузки только отличающихся файлов по SSH.
3. Можно также распаковывать архив бэкапа и класть его в Git. В этом решении больше побочных плюшек (вроде истории изменений файла и возможности отката), но в части использования трафика это всё тот же rsync.

Наконец, можно выкачивать не бэкапы, а просто сам сайт с помощью `rsync`.

Если же вы *любой ценой* хотите чтобы в вашем проекте были только ваши файлы, а все остальное подключалось в виде зависимостей, то это тоже возможно. Для этого вам понадобится менеджер зависимостей, на роль которого каких-то альтернатив [кроме Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) сейчас нет. Потому смотрите ссылки:

- [Инструкция по настройке Composer на совместную работу с WordPress.](https://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/)
- [Репозиторий с плагинами для WordPress](https://wpackagist.org/)

Хватит просмотреть эти страницы по диагонали чтобы понять что с Composer всё становится много сложнее и запутанней чем с просто `git pull` или `rsync -av`. Может быть вам и не нужно так всё усложнять ради идеалов из мира C++.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я хочу репозиторий, в котором только мои данные, без плагинов, и желательно, чтобы все плагины легко устанавливались. Например, когда я занимаюсь разработкой на C++, я не коммичу в репозиторий своего проекта библиотеки, которые он использует. В моём репозитории только мой код и то, как эта библиотека используется, но не она сама.

Comment: Это возможно. Но это не обязательно сделает вашу жизнь проще и легче. Ответ обновил.